# Why doesn't Twitter's follow button widget remember me?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter

I follow people. I go to check out their sites. Many have a 'follow' button with counter like this one

[image: follow]

but if I am I am already following this person the button should be 'grayed' out like this all the time

[image: followed]

but once you refresh the page or return at a later time it looks like I am not a follower. Instead, you need to click the 'follow' button on the site, then twitter's dialog box comes up only to tell me that I am already 'following'

[image: already following blue button]

and when you mouse over this button it says 'unfollow' in red.

[image: unfollow red button]

Do does twitter have some sort of `Follower.Event.Subscribe` function that can recognise people when they are on a site that they 'follow.' If they can recognize follow numbers on a site so why not remember followers?

Answer (score 1):

It come's down Cookies. If the token is not in your browser history how would twitter know that you have clicked it?

What you might find that if you sign into twitter first and then go to the sites and hit refresh it will change to following.

Also if you like me have a tiny Cache for your browser that kills everything on refresh or close then it will definitely not stand a chance at remembering you because your killing the cookie instantly.

---

**UPDATE**

It would seem twitter have changed how the use the follow buttons now.

Before if I was logged into twitter and I pressed follow it would just follow them but now I see a gateway popup with a stream etc.

What seems to have happened is Twitter have stopped cookie dropping and opted for a gateway api.

As for the button the key is in the following code:

```js
! function() {
  Function && Function.prototype && Function.prototype.bind && (/MSIE [678]/.test(navigator.userAgent) || ! function t(e, n, r) {
        function i(s, a) {
          if (!n[s]) {
            if (!e[s]) {
              var u = "function" == typeof require && require;
              if (!a && u) return u(s, !0);
              if (o) return o(s, !0);
              var c = new Error("Cannot find module '" + s + "'");
              throw c.code = "MODULE_NOT_FOUND", c
            }
            var f = n[s] = {
              exports: {}
            };
            e[s][0].call(f.exports, function(t) {
              var n = e[s][1][t];
              return i(n ? n : t)
            }, f, f.exports, t, e, n, r)
          }
          return n[s].exports
        }
        for (var o = "function" == typeof require && require, s = 0; s < r.length; s++) i(r[s]);
        return i
      }({
          1: [
            function(t, e, n) {
              (function() {
                "use strict";

                function t(t) {
                  return "function" == typeof t || "object" == typeof t && null !== t
                }

                function n(t) {
                  return "function" == typeof t
                }

                function r(t) {
                  return "object" == typeof t && null !== t
                }

                function i() {}

                function o() {
                  return function() {
                    process.nextTick(c)
                  }
                }

                function s() {
                  var t = 0,
                    e = new F(c),
                    n = document.createTextNode("");
                  return e.observe(n, {
                      characterData: !0
                    }),
                    function() {
                      n.data = t = ++t % 2
                    }
                }

                function a() {
                  var t = new MessageChannel;
                  return t.port1.onmessage = c,
                    function() {
                      t.port2.postMessage(0)
                    }
                }

                function u() {
                  return function() {
                    setTimeout(c, 1)
                  }
                }

                function c() {
                  for (var t = 0; U > t; t += 2) {
                    var e = q[t],
                      n = q[t + 1];
                    e(n), q[t] = void 0, q[t + 1] = void 0
                  }
                  U = 0
                }

                function f() {}

                function l() {
                  return new TypeError("You cannot resolve a promise with itself")
                }

                function d() {
                  return new TypeError("A promises callback cannot return that same promise.")
                }

                function h(t) {
                  try {
                    return t.then
                  } catch (e) {
                    return J.error = e, J
                  }
                }

                function p(t, e, n, r) {
                  try {
                    t.call(e, n, r)
                  } catch (i) {
                    return i
                  }
                }

                function m(t, e, n) {
                  A(function(t) {
                    var r = !1,
                      i = p(n, e, function(n) {
                        r || (r = !0, e !== n ? w(t, n) : _(t, n))
                      }, function(e) {
                        r || (r = !0, b(t, e))
                      }, "Settle: " + (t._label || " unknown promise"));
                    !r && i && (r = !0, b(t, i))
                  }, t)
                }

                function g(t, e) {
                  e._state === B ? _(t, e._result) : t._state === z ? b(t, e._result) : E(e, void 0, function(e) {
                    w(t, e)
                  }, function(e) {
                    b(t, e)
                  })
                }

                function v(t, e) {
                  if (e.constructor === t.constructor) g(t, e);
                  else {
                    var r = h(e);
                    r === J ? b(t, J.error) : void 0 === r ? _(t, e) : n(r) ? m(t, e, r) : _(t, e)
                  }
                }

                function w(e, n) {
                  e === n ? b(e, l()) : t(n) ? v(e, n) : _(e, n)
                }

                function y(t) {
                  t._onerror && t._onerror(t._result), x(t)
                }

                function _(t, e) {
                  t._state === H && (t._result = e, t._state = B, 0 === t._subscribers.length || A(x, t))
                }

                function b(t, e) {
                  t._state === H && (t._state = z, t._result = e, A(y, t))
                }

                function E(t, e, n, r) {
                  var i = t._subscribers,
                    o = i.length;
                  t._onerror = null, i[o] = e, i[o + B] = n, i[o + z] = r, 0 === o && t._state && A(x, t)
                }

                function x(t) {
                  var e = t._subscribers,
                    n = t._state;
                  if (0 !== e.length) {
                    for (var r, i, o = t._result, s = 0; s < e.length; s += 3) r = e[s], i = e[s + n], r ? O(n, r, i, o) : i(o);
                    t._subscribers.length = 0
                  }
                }

                function T() {
                  this.error = null
                }

                function R(t, e) {
                  try {
                    return t(e)
                  } catch (n) {
                    return W.error = n, W
                  }
                }

                function O(t, e, r, i) {
                  var o, s, a, u, c = n(r);
                  if (c) {
                    if (o = R(r, i), o === W ? (u = !0, s = o.error, o = null) : a = !0, e === o) return void b(e, d())
                  } else o = i, a = !0;
                  e._state !== H || (c && a ? w(e, o) : u ? b(e, s) : t === B ? _(e, o) : t === z && b(e, o))
                }

                function N(t, e) {
                  try {
                    e(function(e) {
                      w(t, e)
                    }, function(e) {
                      b(t, e)
                    })
                  } catch (n) {
                    b(t, n)
                  }
                }

                function C(t, e, n, r) {
                  this._instanceConstructor = t, this.promise = new t(f, r), this._abortOnReject = n, this._validateInput(e) ? (this._input = e, this.length = e.length, this._remaining = e.length, this._init(), 0 === this.length ? _(this.promise, this._result) : (this.length = this.length || 0, this._enumerate(), 0 === this._remaining && _(this.promise, this._result))) : b(this.promise, this._validationError())
                }

                function I() {
                  throw new TypeError("You must pass a resolver function as the first argument to the promise constructor")
                }

                function P() {
                  throw new TypeError("Failed to construct 'Promise': Please use the 'new' operator, this object constructor cannot be called as a function.")
                }

                function S(t) {
                  this._id = X++, this._state = void 0, this._result = void 0, this._subscribers = [], f !== t && (n(t) || I(), this instanceof S || P(), N(this, t))
                }
                var j;
                j = Array.isArray ? Array.isArray : function(t) {
                  return "[object Array]" === Object.prototype.toString.call(t)
                };
                var L, k = j,
                  U = (Date.now || function() {
                    return (new Date).getTime()
                  }, Object.create || function(t) {
                    if (arguments.length > 1) throw new Error("Second argument not supported");
                    if ("object" != typeof t) throw new TypeError("Argument must be an object");
                    return i.prototype = t, new i
                  }, 0),
                  A = function(t, e) {
                    q[U] = t, q[U + 1] = e, U += 2, 2 === U && L()
                  },
                  M = "undefined" != typeof window ? window : {},
                  F = M.MutationObserver || M.WebKitMutationObserver,
                  D = "undefined" != typeof Uint8ClampedArray && "undefined" != typeof importScripts && "undefined" != typeof MessageChannel,
                  q = new Array(1e3);
                L = "undefined" != typeof process && "[object process]" === {}.toString.call(process) ? o() : F ? s() : D ? a() : u();
                var H = void 0,
                  B = 1,
                  z = 2,
                  J = new T,
                  W = new T;
                C.prototype._validateInput = function(t) {
                  return k(t)
                }, C.prototype._validationError = function() {
                  return new Error("Array Methods must be provided an Array")
                }, C.prototype._init = function() {
                  this._result = new Array(this.length)
                };
                var K = C;
                C.prototype._enumerate = function() {
                  for (var t = this.length, e = this.promise, n = this._input, r = 0; e._state === H && t > r; r++) this._eachEntry(n[r], r)
                }, C.prototype._eachEntry = function(t, e) {
                  var n = this._instanceConstructor;
                  r(t) ? t.constructor === n && t._state !== H ? (t._onerror = null, this._settledAt(t._state, e, t._result)) : this._willSettleAt(n.resolve(t), e) : (this._remaining--, this._result[e] = this._makeResult(B, e, t))
                }, C.prototype._settledAt = function(t, e, n) {
                  var r = this.promise;
                  r._state === H && (this._remaining--, this._abortOnReject && t === z ? b(r, n) : this._result[e] = this._makeResult(t, e, n)), 0 === this._remaining && _(r, this._result)
                }, C.prototype._makeResult = function(t, e, n) {
                  return n
                }, C.prototype._willSettleAt = function(t, e) {
                  var n = this;
                  E(t, void 0, function(t) {
                    n._settledAt(B, e, t)
                  }, function(t) {
                    n._settledAt(z, e, t)
                  })
                };
                var V = function(t, e) {
                    return new K(this, t, !0, e).promise
                  },
                  $ = function(t, e) {
                    function n(t) {
                      w(o, t)
                    }

                    function r(t) {
                      b(o, t)
                    }
                    var i = this,
                      o = new i(f, e);
                    if (!k(t)) return b(o, new TypeError("You must pass an array to race.")), o;
                    for (var s = t.length, a = 0; o._state === H && s > a; a++) E(i.resolve(t[a]), void 0, n, r);
                    return o
                  },
                  Y = function(t, e) {
                    var n = this;
                    if (t && "object" == typeof t && t.constructor === n) return t;
                    var r = new n(f, e);
                    return w(r, t), r
                  },
                  G = function(t, e) {
                    var n = this,
                      r = new n(f, e);
                    return b(r, t), r
                  },
                  X = 0,
                  Q = S;
                S.all = V, S.race = $, S.resolve = Y, S.reject = G, S.prototype = {
                  constructor: S,
                  then: function(t, e) {
                    var n = this,
                      r = n._state;
                    if (r === B && !t || r === z && !e) return this;
                    var i = new this.constructor(f),
                      o = n._result;
                    if (r) {
                      var s = arguments[r - 1];
                      A(function() {
                        O(r, i, s, o)
                      })
                    } else E(n, i, t, e);
                    return i
                  },
                  "catch": function(t) {
                    return this.then(null, t)
                  }
                };
                var Z = function() {
                    var t;
                    t = "undefined" != typeof global ? global : "undefined" != typeof window && window.document ? window : self;
                    var e = "Promise" in t && "resolve" in t.Promise && "reject" in t.Promise && "all" in t.Promise && "race" in t.Promise && function() {
                      var e;
                      return new t.Promise(function(t) {
                        e = t
                      }), n(e)
                    }();
                    e || (t.Promise = Q)
                  },
                  tt = {
                    Promise: Q,
                    polyfill: Z
                  };
                "function" == typeof define && define.amd ? define(function() {
                  return tt
                }) : "undefined" != typeof e && e.exports ? e.exports = tt : "undefined" != typeof this && (this.ES6Promise = tt)
              }).call(this)
            }, {}
          ],
          2: [
            function(t, e, n) {
              var r = t(3),
                i = t(36);
              e.exports = function(t, e, n) {
                var o, s, a, u, c = i.aug({}, n);
                return arguments.length > 1 && "[object Object]" !== String(e) ? ((null === e || void 0 === e) && (c.expires = -1), "number" == typeof c.expires && (o = c.expires, s = new Date((new Date).getTime() + 60 * o * 1e3), c.expires = s), e = String(e), r.cookie = [encodeURIComponent(t), "=", c.raw ? e : encodeURIComponent(e), c.expires ? "; expires=" + c.expires.toUTCString() : "", c.path ? "; path=" + c.path : "", c.domain ? "; domain=" + c.domain : "", c.secure ? "; secure" : ""].join("")) : (c = e || {}, u = c.raw ? function(t) {
                  return t
                } : decodeURIComponent, (a = new RegExp("(?:^|; )" + encodeURIComponent(t) + "=([^;]*)").exec(r.cookie)) ? u(a[1]) : null)
              }
            }, {
              3: 3,
              36: 36
            }
          ],
          3: [
            function(t, e, n) {
              e.exports = document
            }, {}
          ],
          4: [
            function(t, e, n) {
              e.exports = location
            }, {}
          ],
          5: [
            function(t, e, n) {
              e.exports = navigator
            }, {}
          ],
          6: [
            function(t, e, n) {
              e.exports = window
            }, {}
          ],
          7: [
            function(t, e, n) {
              function r(t) {
                return a.isType("string", t) ? t.split(".") : a.isType("array", t) ? t : []
              }

              function i(t, e) {
                var n = r(e),
                  i = n.slice(0, -1);
                return i.reduce(function(t, e, n) {
                  if (t[e] = t[e] || {}, !a.isObject(t[e])) throw new Error(i.slice(0, n + 1).join(".") + " is already defined with a value.");
                  return t[e]
                }, t)
              }

              function o(t, e) {
                e = e || s, e[t] = e[t] || {}, Object.defineProperty(this, "base", {
                  value: e[t]
                }), Object.defineProperty(this, "name", {
                  value: t
                })
              }
              var s = t(6),
                a = t(36);
              a.aug(o.prototype, {
                get: function(t) {
                  var e = r(t);
                  return e.reduce(function(t, e) {
                    return a.isObject(t) ? t[e] : void 0
                  }, this.base)
                },
                set: function(t, e, n) {
                  var o = r(t),
                    s = i(this.base, t),
                    a = o.slice(-1);
                  return n && a in s ? s[a] : s[a] = e
                },
                init: function(t, e) {
                  return this.set(t, e, !0)
                },
                unset: function(t) {
                  var e = r(t),
                    n = this.get(e.slice(0, -1));
                  n && delete n[e.slice(-1)]
                },
                aug: function(t) {
                  var e = this.get(t),
                    n = a.toRealArray(arguments).slice(1);
                  if (e = "undefined" != typeof e ? e : {}, n.unshift(e), !n.every(a.isObject)) throw new Error("Cannot augment non-object.");
                  return this.set(t, a.aug.apply(null, n))
                },
                call: function(t) {
                  var e = this.get(t),
                    n = a.toRealArray(arguments).slice(1);
                  if (!a.isType("function", e)) throw new Error("Function " + t + "does not exist.");
                  return e.apply(null, n)
                },
                fullPath: function(t) {
                  var e = r(t);
                  return e.unshift(this.name), e.join(".")
                }
              }), e.exports = o
            }, {
              36: 36,
              6: 6
            }
          ],
          8: [
            function(t, e, n) {
              function r(t) {
                var e, n, r, i = 0;
                for (o = {}, t = t || s, e = t.getElementsByTagName("meta"); n = e[i]; i++) /^twitter:/.test(n.name) && (r = n.name.replace(/^twitter:/, ""), o[r] = n.content)
              }

              function i(t) {
                return o[t]
              }
              var o, s = t(3);
              r(), e.exports = {
                init: r,
                val: i
              }
            }, {
              3: 3
            }
          ],
          9: [
            function(t, e, n) {
              var r = t(7);
              e.exports = new r("__twttr")
            }, {
              7: 7
            }
          ],
          10: [
            function(t, e, n) {
              e.exports = ["hi", "zh-cn", "fr", "zh-tw", "msa", "fil", "fi", "sv", "pl", "ja", "ko", "de", "it", "pt", "es", "ru", "id", "tr", "da", "no", "nl", "hu", "fa", "ar", "ur", "he", "th", "cs", "uk", "vi", "ro", "bn"]
            }, {}
          ],
          11: [
              function(t, e, n) {
                function r(t) {
                  if (t && /^[\w_]{1,20}$/.test(t)) return t;
                  throw new Error("Invalid screen name")
                }

                function i(t, e) {
                  t.className += " " + e
                }

                function o(t) {
                  return t && "false" === t.toLowerCase()
                }

                function s(t) {
                  return st.getElementById(t)
                }

                function a(t) {
                  return t = t || A.event, t && t.preventDefault ? t.preventDefault() : t.returnValue = !1, t && t.stopPropagation ? t.stopPropagation() : t.cancelBubble = !0, !1
                }

                function u(t) {
                    var e = R && R.name ? R.name + " (@" + ut + ")" : "@" + ut;
                    return E ? void(C.title = _("View your profile on Twitter")) : t ? (i(O, "following"), void(C.title = _("You are following %{name} on Twitter", {
                        name: e
                      }))) : (O.className = O.className.replace(/ ?following/, ""), void(C.title = _("Fol…
```

What seem's to be going on here is a handshake with twitters secure server.

So that your information is encrypted.

and all that's happening if the handshake is initiated is that JS is graying out the button.

At no point is this api interacting with the website directly hence why you are not seeing a grayed out button when you are revisiting the site.

It's actually a good think it means that twitter is protecting your privacy as a user.

It also shows that twitter have decided to go down the do not track route for website's so they aren't scoping out a lot of user info.

Sorry about the wait on my answer and the lengthy comment's this must of only happened in recent month's because my last experience with Twitter buttons they had cookie drop's and didnt gateway you like it does now.

Comment: I tested your methods before posting question. Doesn't seem to make a difference. I am logged in. I don't kill cookies or cache.

Comment: It's not really a matter of method's that just how the button work's it uses cookie's there is something at your end stopping the token might even be a firewall or antivirus or even your browser security setting's. For instance IE now comes with privacy positive settings out of the box and attempts to block most kind of behavior tracking which is initiated from the second you first start it up it just gives you a box. IT will 100% be something at your end stopping it. If it is only happening on one browser then its the browser settings if it's happening everywhere on your machine its software

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm stumped.  I have tested in Chrome, Safari and Firefox and two different computers (mac / windows) but same results. No firewalls or antivirus.

Comment: you got a link to the site in question

Comment: Sure, pretty much every site with a follow button. Go to https://dev.twitter.com/web/follow-button and scroll down and follow @twitterdev then refresh screen once grayed out.